# White space between UITableView and Cell when navigation bar is added

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Here is the problem

[screenshot](https://secure.havefun.cz/~kafe/adium_public/xcode-screenshot.png)

There is white space between Cell and TableView beginning. But when i delete the push segue and navigation bar disappear then disappear also the white space. 
And when I run the application with the white space, everything is pretty cool, but tableview doesn't interact, like scrolling or selecting items.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Have you changed anything after dragging and dropping the tableView from the `Object library` onto the Company List View Controller?

Comment: No. Accidentally I made wrong setting with activity indicator – it was problem why tableview didn't interact. But still there is the white space.

Comment: When I set segue to modal, white space is gone but also navigation bar.

Comment: It's hard to remotely debug IB files. You could try to create another VC with the same look and see if this problem exists. If not, you should compare all the views' settings to see what's different there.

Comment: Yes i tried that before but there is same problem each time.

Comment: You can try it too. You have to add navigation controller with rootview relation tableviewcontroller and thereafter add viewcontroller and put tableview into. Everything is alright but then you have to make segue from one tableview to another (like screen).

Comment: [screenshot2](https://secure.havefun.cz/~kafe/adium_public/xcode-screenshot2.png)

Comment: Does Category Controller contain a Collection View?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter what you are using.